# Angular Js: refer all js files in index.cshtml

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular js.
In my angular js App, I  have views (Not partial views.) where in its controller and service js files are referred in same view.

Now as per my requirement I want to put all js files in index.html (landing page of website) and all remaining views should work just like before they are working.

But after moving all js files to index.cshtml, remaining views started giving errors.

Please let me know how to accomplish.

Comment: Why not put in your layout file?  Can you post your code for reference?

Comment: You'll need to tell us at least one of those errors for us to know what you're talking about. The code before/after would be handy as well.